# Looking at the faults in my question? I can't see what I did wrong

Tags: support

How do I properly ask [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044958/ie-doesnt-run-remote-js-properly-but-local-runs-fine) question, because I do not know what I did wrong here.

I did make two faults in my sentences, but I edited them out pretty quick.

I really want my questions to be as clear as possible, but I sometimes have trouble forming sentences.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would say a couple of things. You are not very specific in terms of what is wrong. I see this all the time - someone says "it does not work", but then they don't specify "it" and they don't say what "does not work" means.

For your reference, here is your text:

> I recently uploaded this page and saw that everything worked as expected on almost every browser except IE 10 so i made some (non-relevant) edits and reopened the page locally and came to the conclusion that nothing was wrong, but i made changes so i re-uploaded the page but still remotely the page did not draw properly due to the JS not running properly. On every browser this page works perfectly fine except for IE. So only not in Internet Explorer 10 when run remotely

If I look at your text above, I can only guess what is wrong. Is an image not aligned? Does something not display at all? Is there an animation that is supposed to run? I have no idea.

The other thing that is wrong with your post is that it appears you have posted your entire javacript file. No one wants to read the entire file to try to figure out what is wrong.

It comes down to being as specific as possible, and to only include relevant bits of code.

Answer (score 4):

You never say what the page is supposed to look like, or describe how it looks instead in IE. You just show a wall of code and ask people to figure these things out for themselves. It would have been much better to include screenshots from a good browser and from IE, and to narrow down the code the the smallest possible excerpt that shows the problem.

Also, the long paragraph at the beginning is mostly unnecessary rambling: it can be summarized as "This page doesn't display properly in IE". That's awfully vague, and it would be much better to specifically describe what's wrong with the display.